# How can a function accept a colon (range operator) as an argument (in Python)?

Tags: python, function, arguments, recurrence

I want to do the following: I want to define a recursive function `funct` in which the last reference of itself return a number of the array `temp`. The problem is that `funct` must do an integral of itself (see the code below) and this would be very easy if `funct` could accept the colon `:` as an argument. So, I have this (simplified) code so far:

```
import numpy as np   
import scipy.integrate as ints

temp = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[4,0,6,7,8],[7,8,9,10,11],[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]])

def funct(x,y,n):
    if n>1:
        return (temp[x,y] + ints.cumtrapz(temp[x,:]*funct(:,y,n-1), x=None, dx=1, initial=0)[-1])
    else:
        return temp[x,y]
funct = np.vectorize(funct)
funct(1,1,3)
```

The problem is that `funct` can't accept the colon `:` as argument, it doesn't matter if I want to *vectorize* to `funct` later in the code.

For instance, If I change this part of the above code

```
ints.cumtrapz(temp[x,:]*funct(:,y,n-1), x=None, dx=1, initial=0)[-1])
```

for

```
ints.cumtrapz(temp[x,:]*temp[:,y], x=None, dx=1, initial=0)[-1])
```

I have no problems. I just want to do the last part recursively.

Comment: A colon is not a range operator for Python or an ```ndarray```.  What dp ypu want to pass as the argument?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, Python doesn't have "range operators" like some other languages. The `:` generates `slice`s, which are a completely different type from `range`s. And, more importantly, the `:` syntax is part of the [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings) (aka extended indexing or extended subscription) syntax, it doesn't stand on its own.

So, the simple way to write your code is to use a `slice` literal:

Of course you could also avoid all this mess and just use an explicit slice literal:

```
def funct(x, y, n):
    if n>1:
        return (temp[x,y] + ints.cumtrapz(temp[x,:]*funct(slice(None),y,n-1), x=None, dx=1, initial=0)[-1])
    else:
        return temp[x,y]
```

---

So, why isn't there a syntax for "slice literals" that's more convenient than calling the `slice` constructor? Because nobody's come up with a compelling argument, worked out potential syntax ambiguities, and submitted a patch.*

<sub>* Note that Python *did* add a syntax for ellipsis literals on their own—`...` is a literal for `Ellipsis`, the singleton value of type `ellipsis`. A lot of people wanted that, there were no ambiguities except in code that was already illegal, someone wrote a patch, and it was accepted with little fuss.</sub>

---

While the syntax for extended indexing and the syntax for function calls are somewhat similar, they're not identical. That means you can't use function calls as, e.g., a domain-specific language for wrapping up delayed slicing.

One thing you *can* do is create a slice-wrapper type, to using slicing expressions themselves as such a domain-specific language:

```
class Slicer:
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return idx
s = Slicer()
```

Now `s[:]` is a constructor for `slice(None)`, and `s[3:23:2, ..., 4]` is a constructor for `(slice(3, 23, 2), Ellipsis, 4)`. So you can write things like this:

```
funct(s[:,y,n-1])
```

Your `funct` class will get a tuple of `slice` objects and integers, which it can later use to index an array by calling its `__getitem__` directly.

And you can wrap up more of that if you want. For example:

```
class SliceCallable(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if isinstance(idx, collections.abc.Sequence):
            return self.f(*idx)
        else:
            return self.f(idx)
    def __call__(self, *args):
        return self.f(*args)

@SliceCallable
def funct(x, y, n):
    if n>1:
        return (temp[x,y] + ints.cumtrapz(temp[x,:]*funct[:,y,n-1], x=None, dx=1, initial=0)[-1])
    else:
        return temp[x,y]
```

Now, `funct` can be called as either `funct(1, 2, 3)` or `funct[1, 2, 3]`—or as `funct[:, 2, 3]` or `funct[4:-1]`. That just means that `x` will be `slice(None, None, None)` or `slice(4, -1, None)`. And you can use that in an indexing expression; `temp[slice(None, None), 3]` may not look as nice as `temp[:, 3]`, but it means the same thing.

Comment: Note for the particular use of `numpy`, you can use e.g. `np.s_[4:6]` to return a `slice` object.  See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html